# link doesn't work in production in middleware next js

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware

in my nextJs project. I use middleware for redirect link....

here is my code

```
    import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
    switch (pathname) {
        case '/recent':
            return NextResponse.redirect('/explore')
      
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

in development mode work good but in production I get this error and all of header link made disable

[image]

are there any solution?

Comment: Do you also have the `config: { matcher: [...]...` in your middleware file?